# Multiple column INDEX and single column INDEX SQL/PHP

Tags: mysql

This is my SQL table, a huge table with around ~6kk rows.

```
CREATE TABLE `slots` (
    `id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `uid` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `music_id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `finished` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `completed` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `hidden` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `slots`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ADD KEY `SEC_UNQ` (`uid`,`music_id`) USING BTREE;

ALTER TABLE `slots` MODIFY `id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

I'm looking frequently after `uid`, `music_id` and `completed`. For example:

```
SELECT `music_id` FROM `slots` WHERE `uid` = :uid AND `completed` = :completed;
```

and SELECT or UPDATE by `uid` and `music_id`

```
 SELECT `music_id` FROM `slots` WHERE **`uid` = :uid AND `music_id` = :music_id**;
 UPDATE `slots` SET xxx WHERE `uid` = :uid AND `music_id` = :music_id;
```

so the question is:

I have to create 3 indexes for all of the following columns: **uid**, **music_id** and **completed** or it's enough only for **uid** ?
..and which is better, single column index or multi-column indexes?

PS: I always have **uid** in WHERE statement

Thank you in advance

Comment: If `uid` and `music_id` are key for other tables, you should definitely create an index so you can create foreign keys (and enforce foreign key constraints). `completed` must absolutely not be indexed (because it is a boolean). Indexes are meant for columns with lot a of different values, not column with only two possible values (in those cases, they overload the table uselessly during `insert`, `update` and `delete` while not adding any speed up on reading operation) .

Comment: @JonathanParentLévesque thanks for your answer! but when i should use multiple column index and when i should use single column index?

Comment: Use multiple column on an index when you use them together most of the time (by example in a transition table when both the vehicle id and the customer id are used as PK). When you use multiple column for an index (in cases when they are not PK), make sure that you use the field that is most likely to be used alone first, because the first fields in a multiple colums index can be used alone, but the second column will not be used as an index by the engine if used without the first column. Most of time, you want to use multiple column indexes on tables that already have lots indexes.

Comment: Multiple row indexes are also useful when you need to ensure uniqueness of two (or more) rows in and those are not used in primary key. By example, I might want to use an auto incremental key as primary key in a vehicle model table (so I can used a single foreign key field to refer to the model in a vehicle table) but, obviously, I want the combination of make id and the model name to be unique (as you cannot have two vehicle model with the same name for the same  vehicle make).

Comment: @JonathanParentLévesque thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easy test it. A good index is always the best, also for small Type Boolean. It is realy easy to understand: If you have a large table mysql must read the hole table (FULL TABLE SCAN) to find a few row to update or delete. BUT MySQL can mostly only use one index per query. So a composite index is helpfull. and MySQL can also use them for single fields. Lets say you have a composite index on field (a,b,c) MySQL can use them in the WHERE Clause if only a , a and b or a and b and c , but not only on c or b.

Hier is a sample. there you can see how man rows MySQL must read and which index are used:

**Drop Table and create a new**

```
MariaDB []> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.29 sec)

MariaDB []>
MariaDB []> CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
    ->   `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ->   `a` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `b` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `c` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.24 sec)

MariaDB []>
```

**Insert 3000000 ROWS (only MariaDB)**

```
MariaDB []> INSERT INTO mytable (id,a,b,c)
    -> SELECT seq, (seq MOD 2), (seq MOD 3) , (seq MOD 4) FROM seq_0_to_3000000;
Query OK, 3000001 rows affected (15.66 sec)
Records: 3000001  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB []>
```

**Test WHERE on field a - MySQL reads 2995634 rows**

```
MariaDB []> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE a=1;
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2995634 | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.12 sec)
```

**Add a Key on Field a**

```
MariaDB []> ALTER TABLE mytable ADD KEY key_a (a);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (10.74 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**Test the last query again (WHERE a) - MySQL reads only 1496635 rows**

```
MariaDB []> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE a=1;
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+---------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+---------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | ref  | key_a         | key_a | 5       | const | 1496635 |       |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Test with WHERE on fiels a and b - 1496635 rows**

```
MariaDB []> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE a=1 AND b=2;
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | ref  | key_a         | key_a | 5       | const | 1496635 | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Add key on field b**

```
MariaDB []> ALTER TABLE mytable ADD KEY key_b (b);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (9.53 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**Same test with a and b - same rows - only use key_a**

```
MariaDB []> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE a=1 AND b=2;
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | ref  | key_a,key_b   | key_a | 5       | const | 1496635 | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Create index on a and b**

```
MariaDB []> ALTER TABLE mytable ADD KEY key_ab (a,b);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (11.86 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**Test with a and b - use key_ab and only 946702 rows read**

```
MariaDB []> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE a=1 AND b=2;
+------+-------------+---------+------+--------------------+--------+---------+-------------+--------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys      | key    | key_len | ref         | rows   | Extra |
+------+-------------+---------+------+--------------------+--------+---------+-------------+--------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | ref  | key_a,key_b,key_ab | key_ab | 10      | const,const | 946702 |       |
+------+-------------+---------+------+--------------------+--------+---------+-------------+--------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Test with field a,b and c -- kay_ab used and 946702 rows read**

```
MariaDB []> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE a=1 AND b=2 AND c=3;
+------+-------------+---------+------+--------------------+--------+---------+-------------+--------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys      | key    | key_len | ref         | rows   | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------+------+--------------------+--------+---------+-------------+--------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | ref  | key_a,key_b,key_ab | key_ab | 10      | const,const | 946702 | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------+------+--------------------+--------+---------+-------------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Add Key on field a,b,c**

```
MariaDB []> ALTER TABLE mytable ADD KEY key_abc (a,b,c);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (18.64 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**Test with field a,b,c - key_abc used - and 511082 rows read**

```
MariaDB []> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE a=1 AND b=2 AND c=3;
+------+-------------+---------+------+----------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------+--------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys              | key     | key_len | ref               | rows   | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------+------+----------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------+--------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | ref  | key_a,key_b,key_ab,key_abc | key_abc | 15      | const,const,const | 511082 | Using index |
+------+-------------+---------+------+----------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

So the most effect is on composite index, but it also depends on your used querys.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation! It will help me a lot! Thank you!